# Need to Extend the Scope of a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, scope, ms-access-2010

I'm converting old VB 7 code which used ODBC to connect to an SQL Anywhere DB to VB 2013 and an Access 2010 DB.

I declare several DataSets at the top of the module but when I get into procedures and functions, I have lost the scope of the DataTable.

I have the following declared:

```
Public con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CLI_CRVM.accdb")

Public extractDA As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [extract]", con)
Public extractCB = New OleDbCommandBuilder(extractDA)
Public extractDT As DataTable
Public extractDR As DataRow
```

Then, in a clicked event of a button, I call a procedure which loads the DataTable:

```
extractCB.quoteprefix = "["
extractCB.quotesuffix = "]"
extractDT = New DataTable
extractDA.Fill(extractDT)
```

When it returns to the clicked event code, it does a For Each loop:

```
For Each extractDR As System.Data.DataRow In extractDT.Rows
```

At this point, I can see values from the DataTable like this:

```
ls_plan_code = Trim(extractDR("plan_code"))
MsgBox("Plan Code: " & ls_plan_code)
```

But when I call a procedure or function where I need the values from the DataTable, they are no longer available.  Ie. when this executes:

```
Sub accumulation(ByVal adec_premium As Decimal, ByVal ai_stage As Integer)
    Dim ldec_mode As Decimal
    ldec_mode = CDec(extractDR("pay_mode"))
End Sub
```

I get this error:  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I know a workaround is to pass the DataRow to the sub routine; however, there are several DataTables and many procedures and functions, some of which call other procedures and functions which rely on data from other DataTables.  Additionally, some sub routines write values to an answer DataTable which then gets written to the Access DB.

So, while I know this may not be "proper" form, I've got to get this code up and running to test values and if there were a way - as it did in the VB 7 code - to get the scope of the DataTable to extend throughout the entire module, I think my problems will be solved.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line:

```
For Each extractDR As System.Data.DataRow In extractDT.Rows
```

By specifying `extractDR As System.Data.DataRow`, you are creating a *new* variable. This variable is being assigned the value instead of the variable with the same name in the higher scope.

Simply remove the `As System.Data.DataRow`:

```
For Each extractDR In extractDT.Rows
```